# Is there a way to grant IAM user view permissions for the DynamoDB table using browser, not programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I was asked to grant an IAM user DynamoDB table view permission, but the issue is that the user should be accessing the table using the browser (similar to https://console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodbv2/home?region=REGION-HERE#table?name=TABLE-NAME-HERE) .
I'm aware of the policy to grant read only permissions when using CLI. But not sure if there is a way to enable the browser access.

Thanks ahead

Igal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the user uses the CLI tool, an SDK, the API or the Console UI, it is the same set of permissions that is enforced. You'll just need to check (maybe through trial-and-error) that the user also has the permissions needed to navigate to the table using the console, meaning you'll need more permissions than just the read permissions on the table itself.

Comment: thank you, @stijndepestel. I'll check it out

Comment: thank you so much, @stijndepestel! It worked, I marked your answer as an answer